# eCommerce membership subscription after payment

Tags: php, database, paypal, e-commerce

I am creating a site in which a user must pay in order to access certain parts of the site. I understand how to make certain pages available to certain users, but I would like to know how I can automatically give them access once their payment has been processed.

ex.) A user sets up a account, during the process it will ask for credit card or other payment info(I would like it to be through Paypal). Once the payment has been processed it will add the user to my database and then they can access the site.

I am new to eCommerce and would like to know what tools I can use so that when a purchase on my site has been processed, I allow the user to access the website.

note: My site is being built with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) for that.

It's basically a script that sits on your server listening for data.  Any time your PayPal account has a transaction that takes place it will automatically push data to your listener script in real-time.  Within that script you can update your database, send out email notifications, etc.

Here's a [PHP template for IPN](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-paypal-ipn-template/) that I developed years ago. It's a little rudimentary, but still very useful and will get you up-and-running with IPN within minutes.  Then all you would need to do is make some basic additions to update your users table accordingly, but the template comes with a nice database class that makes that very simple as well (assuming you install the IPN template solution to the same DB as your users table.)